# Displaying the result of an AJAX request using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have a webservice that returns an XML.

Code that gets the XML:

```
function PostToService()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:53247/api/student/studentstatus",
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: "<StudentStatus><ID>C101</ID><Score>56</Score></StudentStatus>",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        Accept: "text/xml",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

I can see the returned XML in Devtools console expanding the #document:

```
<UpdatedStudent>
    <StudentID>C101</StudentID>
    <Result>Pass</Result>
<UpdatedStudent>
```

Tried creating a div with an id of response and used this code:

```
 $("#response").html(data);
```

Get this error in the Console:

```
Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
```

How do I show the response to the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you code:

```
$("#response").html(data);
```

and your data is XML text you are saying that you wish XML to be used as HTML text and that won't work unless the XML is indeed an HTML document.  The browser will try and interpret the XML as HTML and fail.  If all you wish to do is display the XML, try the following:

```
$("#response").text(data);
```